# Python won't pull Windows system environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have been trying to no avail to pull an environment variable from my windows system with Python. I have tried os.getenv() and os.environ.get(), but neither seem to have worked.

I have a feeling that "Environment Variable" might refer to two different things, or that python may not have access to the environment variables so it makes up its own. I am trying to pull the information stored in the environment variable that is set by going to system > advanced system settings > environment variables.

I am able to get the "PATH" environment variable in python, but it seems to be different than the one in the windows setting.

Comment: What happens if you print out just `os.environ`? It's the `dict` itself and would show what the environment variables are that the Python process sees. Also note that if you're, say, running this in Powershell/cmd and then you make changes to the system vars (via the control panel), those aren't going to be updated in any existing powershell/cmd windows.

Comment: @wkl If I print that out in Ubuntu I get a dictionary with stuff like PATH and USER and HOME, but I don't see the variable I defined. I defined this variable before, reset my system, then openened Ubuntu btw

Comment: Also it should be noted that my intent is for others to define an environment variable on their own systems with the same name that will store log-in parameters and then run my python program

Comment: How did you “define” this variable in Ubuntu? Most environment variables are temporary and if you reset your machine, it may have been deleted/wiped by the restart.

Comment: I never "defined" the variable in Ubuntu. I defined it as a system variable and it's still there after the reset. I just don't know how to pull info from it.

Comment: If you just added the variable, reboot or log out and in again. You get the environment variables from your parent process, and your parent process (if the command line for example) doesn’t get updated when you update variables in the system settings without restarting it from the deskop. Logging out or rebooting make sure every process gets the new variable

Comment: There are multiple things that can interact here that muck it up. Are your system variables set in `/etc/environment`? `/etc/profile.d`? Did you set them in some type of GUI tool (though I don't think there are any such normal tools in Ubuntu for this)? Are you only setting your variable for a specific user? Are you trying to run this script via `sudo`? If you can give a full description of how you're actually setting these variables in Ubuntu, and how you're running this Python code (shell? some type of IDE? etc.) that would be helpful.

Comment: I used the builtin System Settings on Windows to set the variable. It appears that the variables were not set in either environment or profile.d, only PATH existed in environment. I am not running sudo, I tried simply running "import os" and "os.getenv(variable)" in ubuntu terminal after running "python3"

Comment: Interesting. I tried getting it with the command prompt and it actually did work. Is there a way I can automatically define all the environment variables with Ubuntu?

Comment: @JonathanBear usually you set this in your per-user config (like `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` under Linux/Unix-y systems), a system-level configuration (like `/etc/profile` though do note that means every user will get these variables). In Windows the environment settings GUI is the normal way to do it that would affect any console/shell-like environment (cmd, powershell).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was that I was trying to run my code in an environment that was different from my system environment. Running the code via command prompt worked, and it worked in VS Code when I defined the environment in the "launch.json" file.